# Stabilizer in the definition of a Gelfand pair

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups, group-actions

I am following the textbook *Representation Theory of the Symmetric Groups*, by Tullio C.-S., Fabio S., and Filippo T., and am confused at the definition of a Gelfand pair.

The definition is:

Let $G$ act transitively on a set $X$. Fix $x_0 \in X$ and denote its stabilizer by $K=\{g \in G : g x_0 = x_0\}$. We can identify $X$ with the space of right cosets of $K$ in $G$ $(X = G/K)$. If the permutation representation $\lambda$ of $G$ has a decomposition that is multiplicity-free, then $(G,K)$ is a Gelfand pair.

Here the permutation representation is the representation of $G$ on $L(X)$, the space of complex functions on $X$, where:

$$[\lambda (g)f](x) = f(g^{-1}x)$$

I don't understand why $K$ is necessary in the definition. We can identify $X$ with $G/K$, but the action works on $X$ just the same. Doesn't this mean that all the stabilizers on $X$ form a Gelfand pair with $G$? What's the point of mentioning $K$ at all?

Comment: A better question is why mention $X$ at all?

Comment: $X$ is important, since $L(X)$ is the $FG$-module associated with $\lambda$, so I think $\lambda$ is dependent on $X$ and the action of $G$ on it.

Comment: No, $X$ is irrelevant. You can frame everything without referring to $X$ at all: Let $G$ act on the coset space $G/K$. We say that the pair $(G,K)$ is a Gelfand pair if the corresponding permutation representation is multiplicity free.

Comment: So by corresponding permutation representation, I should be thinking of it on the space $L(G/K)$?

Comment: Yes, exactly right.